# PrincipalContext ValidateCredentials .NET framework

Tags: active-directory, .net-4.5

I try to validate AD credentials using the next method call on a `PrincipalContext` object and it fails with the error:

> The server cannot handle directory requests

Code:

```
// default ContextOptions per MSDN are Negotiate+Signing+Sealing
principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password)
```

Then I tried to call the method where I put `ContextOptions` explicitly and it works:

```
principalContext.ValidateCredentials(userName, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing)
```

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contextoptions?view=netframework-4.5) the default `ContextOptions` for the first call are exactly the same as I provided in the second call. So, my expectations are that they either should both work or both fail.

Any idea why it behaves differently?

**UPDATE:**
Context is defined as the following for both cases:

```
var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain");
```

Comment: How are you declaring `principalContext`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I added an update regarding context initialization